# Skype For Business Online supproted by Azure AD 2.0?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business

I developed an app which has integration with Microsoft Graph API and uses Azure 2.0 API for authentication.
From Microsoft Graph I can get users.
Now I want to see a presense information for each user and therefore I need to use Skype for business online.

I send request to:

```
https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root
```

And a user href is:

```
https://webdir0f.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user
```

Than I got access token for `https://webdir0f.online.lync.com` from:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<mytenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

And token has not "roles" claim which is strange.
Than `https://webdir0f.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user` returns me 500.

Is there a way to use Azure 2.0 to get access to Skype For Business Online?
Is there a way I can get presence information without a signed in user in Skype For Business Online?

UPD:
I was able to get access token for scope `https://webdir0f.online.lync.com/Contacts.ReadWrite` using client secret.

Comment: If you're getting errors this morning, it's likely due to a current outage situation with Azure, which is have a direct impact on Azure AD. Please check the AzureSupport twitter account, as well as the Azure status dashboard, for more info. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: Thanks! Actually my question in general is like this: Is it possible to authorize Azure 2.0 Application for Skype For Business ? Looks like I can't get proper "aud" claim to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get access to Skype For Business using Azure 2.0 application. Just followed the guidelines. 
During autodiscovery you need to set scope to next user or redirect uri like this: `https://webdir0f.online.lync.com/Contacts.ReadWrite`.

Than Azure 2.0 realizes it's Skype For Business uri and scope and works properly.
Though still Skype For Business API is old and very hard to use.

And I haven't found a way to get all other company user presence information from Sfb API.
Looks like it makes sense to wait until Trusted Application API will work.

Also trying to get Application token doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain where  - supplied permissions using 'Contacts.ReadWrite'?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, sorry. But as I mentioned you can't get "Implicit Auth". Only full OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Small correction, what you're here isn't "Azure 2.0" but rather Azure Active Directory's "App v2" or, more commonly, the "v2 Endpoint".

The v2 Endpoint has several [well-known limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations) and not all APIs and features are supported. The Skype and Skype for Business APIs both lack support for the v2 Endpoint.

In general, unless it's a recently released API or it is surfaced by Microsoft Graph, then it will only work with tokens issued by the v1 Endpoint.

Comment: Well yeah. Azure AD 2.0 (v2 Endpoint). By now I managed to get access and went through all of autodiscovery process supplying permissons Contacts.ReadWrite for each autodiscovery hop. And finally I got /applications so now I think the answer is yes, it's possible. Tomorrow I will try to read presence.

Comment: By the way if there's another way of syncing user presence from SFB to my service daemon in background than logging in a user - I'd like to know about it. Looks like Microsoft.Graph lacks support here. And Trusted Application as well.

Comment: @norekhov - Can you explain how - supplied permissions using 'Contacts.ReadWrite'?